# How to associate a Individual email result record to Opportunity in Salesforce?

Tags: marketing-cloud, opportunity, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, email-tracking

I have a journey in Marketing Cloud which runs on the Opportunity records in Salesforce. Whenever an email is sent out of the journey record an "Individual Email Result" record (email tracking record) is created on the associated Contact in Salesforce and not on the Opportunity record.

I am looking for a way where the email tracking record (Individual Email Result) can be directly associated or shown in the related list of the Opportunity in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to my question here: [How do you automatically assign an Salesforce Campaign to a Salesforce send within SFMC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246088/how-do-you-automatically-assign-an-salesforce-campaign-to-a-salesforce-send-with)

You'll need to send on the Opportunity record to be able to see the Individual Email Result on the Opportunity object related list.

Alternatively, you can manually relate the Individual Email Result to the Opportunity.

Comment: ,I think my use-case is some what different from yours, you want to assign a email send to a campaign but I want to assign a Individual email result to a opportunity record which is associated to a contact record through it's related Account. To make it similar to your use case, I want to assign the Individual Email result record to a campaign member but I do not know the campaign name since the record will be created on the contact and a contact can contain more than one IER records on it.

Comment: @JiteshGoel - did you find a solution to this? I am looking for the same thing.